# Xcode: skip test if previous one failed

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

Is there any option in Xcode to skip the test in test-class if previous one failed?

Now I use something like that in potentially skippable test body:

```
if previousTestFailed == true {
    XCTFail("Test can't proceed because previous one failed")
}
```

Maybe there is something more pleasant?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for [continueafterfailure](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496260-continueafterfailure)

Comment: Do you mean a test case failed, or an assertion in the same test failed?

Comment: Your tests should be independent from each other and set themselves up adequately so that they can be run in any order. That's the reason it's not easy to do what you're doing.

Comment: @Jon Reid, if an assertion in previous test failed.
The first test is more general, and if it fails then there's no much matter to run the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Tests must function independently of each other. This is especially important when running one test in isolation. [Xcode 10 will help enforce this independence by giving the option to shuffle test order](https://qualitycoding.org/random-test-order/).

To terminate a test when a precondition fails, just test for that precondition, even if that means repeating some code from the more fundamental test. XCTFail if the precondition is not met.

If the precondition applies to multiple tests, extract it to a helper. Then the tests can do something like

```
if !meetsPrecondition() {
    XCTFail("Precondition not met")
    return
}
```